# Adding External boostrap link to only one component in Angular8

Tags: angular, hyperlink, components

I want to use this for only one component in my Angular project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

How can I do that? (not for index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a stylesheet only work for 1 component in angular that reliable mitigates namespace collisions.
Maybe we can find an alternative solution if you describe your motivation behind that idea. Do you want to mitigate different versions of bootstrap in your project?

Comment: I just want to add an class pre-defined in boostrap. It works only for above link. If I linked in index.html whole project changes to that class's css. That's why I asked is there any way to use it only for this page. Any answers please?